# Откуда выкачивать шрифты для @font-face и что за стили мне отдает Google Fonts?

Tags: css, шрифты, google-fonts

Всем привет.

Нужно к проекту прикрутить локально **Open Sans**. Шрифт бесплатный, от гуглей. Глупый вопрос, но где взять? Проблема получить именно сами файлы.

У гугл фонтс есть возможность сконфигурировать шрифт: выбрать нужные языки, например, кириллицу и латиницу и проигнорировать, например, вьетнамский и греческий. Они отдают нужные мне woff2 и woff. То, что нужно! Но как забрать у них сами файлы?

Если я в браузере открываю ссылку на гугловую CSS-ку, типа:
https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans+Condensed:300,700|Open+Sans:300,400,400i,600&subset=cyrillic

то я не понимаю три вещи:

1) Почему и как для разных браузеров конфигурируются разные файлы? Для одних файлы с woff2, для других woff?

2) Почему в этой CSS-ке я получаю font-fac`ы для всех языков? И как они вообще уживаются вместе?

[image: Google fonts font-face]

3) Как работает unicode-range и как на него реагируют разные браузеры?

Судя по всему google fonts определяет браузер. Если я захожу с IE, то мне отадется font-face в котором по одному файлу woff для каждого начертания, потому что IE не умеет woff2. Должно быть это правильные файлы сконфигурированные только под кириллицу и латиницу. Если все верно, то я могу просто скачать эти файлы и использовать в своем проекте. Все верно?

Если я захожу с хрома, то мне отдаются font-fac`ы с woff2 для всех возможных языков помеченныe unicode-range. Гугл фонтс знает, что мой браузер понимает unicode-range и скачает только нужные мне файлы для языков используемых на странице. Если все верно, то я могу так же скачать woff2 файлы по адресам в font-face для нужной мне латиницы и кириллицы и использовать соответсвующий unicode-range. Верно?

Тут, правда, проблема. Я точно знаю, что в моем проекте есть только латиница и кириллица и мне два woff2 файла с unicode-range не нужны. Мне бы хватило одного сразу с двумя языками, по аналогии с woff.

Вот. Помогите, пожалуйста, уложить эту кашу в голове и скачать уже нужные мне файлы. Спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

[На странице с шрифтом](http://www.google.com/fonts/#UsePlace:use/Collection:Open+Sans)

Кликнуть стрелку, и нажать скачать как на скриншоте.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Там же на странице ты можешь выбрать какие именно тебе нужны элементы шрифта.

Ответ взят: [отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14170113/is-it-possible-to-download-open-sans-as-available-on-google-fonts-to-use-on-my-d)

Comment: К сожалению они отдают только .ttf 
Конвертировать придется самому и я немного побаиваюсь. Думаю в гугл это получается лучше :)
Кроме того это, получается, файлы со всеми возможными символами, включая греческий, вьетнамский и т.д.

Comment: @Cypher можешь напрямую по ссылкам с твоего скриншота скачать их, в чем проблема?) И он тебе отдает нужные шрифты с выбранными слева видами его отрисовки

Comment: Проблема во-первых осмыслить это, во-вторых добыть woff2 для двух нужных мне языков. Гугл фонтс отдает woff2 по отдельности для каждого возможного языка, и чтобы их "переключать" нужно использовать unicode-range, а чтобы его хорошенько использовать нужно детектить браузер :)
Я бы хотел просто написать src: local, ...woff2, src: woff

Comment: А если выдернуть все остальные и оставить только кирилицу, сделайте свою версию этого cssника, ну а сами шрифты выкачайте

Comment: Нужна латиница и кириллица в одном файле. Гугл фонтс отдает двумя разными и разруливает это через unicode-range.